# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused while trying to open Firefox browser through GeckoDriver in Raspberry-pi3

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi3, geckodriver

Hi I have a raspberry pi 3 and decided to try get selenium running with python 3. I installed it using "pip3 install selenium" and there were no errors. After I made a small test script with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.clear()

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("Selenium WebDriver Interview questions")
search_field.submit()

# get the list of elements which are displayed after the search
# currently on result page using find_elements_by_class_name method
lists= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")

# get the number of elements found
print ("Found " + str(len(lists)) + " searches:")

# iterate through each element and print the text that is
# name of the search

i=0
for listitem in lists:
   print (listitem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
   i=i+1
   if(i>10):
      break

# close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/SeleniumTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Web Client* session/instance successfully.

The version information of the binaries you are using in-terms of might have given us some more insights into the error you are observing.

However you may need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* as an argument while initializing the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/path/to/geckodriver')
```

### Additional Recommendations

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is present in the specified location as mentioned through the argument **executable_path**.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v59.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you! I reinstalled the image on raspberry pi and got firefox to the latest version. Now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the geckodriver, it's a requirement, I don't know if is available by apt, but if not you can download the armv7hf version from its official release page on GitHub https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

If you need to install it manually, extract the executable `geckodriver` to a directory in path, usually `/usr/local/bin` or '$HOME/bin`

EDIT:
Another possible cause is running selenium over SSH, in this scenario your RPi won't have a display to attach the firefox window to and it will crash, to solve this you need to run Firefox in headless mode like this:

```
# create a new Firefox session
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.set_headless()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt)
# here instead of maximize you have to set a custom size
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Comment: then this sounds like a firefox and geckodriver incompatibility, do you have the latest version of both applications?

Comment: Another possible issue is if you are running your test over SSH, in this case there's no display for firefox to open a window. The solution for this case is running Firefox in headless mode, I'll update the answer to reflect this

Comment: Wait I updated my geckodriver to latest version but I only installed firefox a couple of hours ago. Although I did install iceweasel instead of firefox

Comment: Just to tell you what happens. It opens up firefox on a blank page and then like 20 seconds later prints the error and keeps firefox open